# Robocopy: Copy all files in subdirectories within parent folder to a new folder

Tags: windows, robocopy, files-folders

I've done some googling and although this seems to be a pretty straightforward process I have been unable to find code that works.

I have a folder with several sub-folders and sub-folders within them which contain files. I want to move all the files into a new folder without any directory structure so I can view them all at once instead of going through folders.

Would really appreciate any help you can provide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What about duplicate file names from different subfolders, you can't have two named the same in the same folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This batch file copies all files in source sub-folders to one folder and renames the files in case there are files with the same name in the sub-folder structure:

```
@echo off

set Source=Test
set Destiny=Banana

if not exist "%Source%" exit
if not exist "%Destiny%" md "%Destiny%"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b /a-d "%Source%\*.*"') do if not exist "%Destiny%\%%~nxa" (move "%%a" "%Destiny%\") else (
                                                                                                                            set Contador=1
                                                                                                                            call :Rename "%%~a"
                                                                                                                           )

popd
exit
    
:Rename
set /a Contador+=1
if exist "%Destiny%\%~n1 (%Contador%).%~x1" (goto :Rename) else (move "%~1" "%Destiny%\%~n1 (%Contador%).%~x1")
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Thanks. I renamed my source folder to 'Source' and created a destination folder called 'Destiny' but it didn't work. What is the significance of 'Test' and 'Banana' in the script?

Comment: In source you are supposed to put the path to the source folder, in destiny you put the path where you want to save the files...

Comment: Sorry that was silly of me, I'm not familiar with scripting. Thank you so much, that worked brilliantly!

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions from the post
[How to copy files from folder tree dropping all the folders with Robocopy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502170/how-to-copy-files-from-folder-tree-dropping-all-the-folders-with-robocopy)

- In a Command Prompt (CMD), set the current folder to the source folder
  (use `cd`) and enter the following command:

  ```
  for /r %f in (*) do @copy "%f" target
  ```
- To specify the directory to start in:

  ```
  for /r FolderA %f in (*) do @copy "%f" target
  ```